# How to wire up a bean with different implementations depending on properties nicely?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently looking for a better solution to wire up a bean with varying implementations. The concrete implementation depends on the provided application.properties, which changes from stage to stage.

Let's take a look at the concrete classes:

- Interface: FtpWriter
- Implementations: SftpWriter, DefaultFtpWriter

Usually I would do something like this:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("writer.ftp")
public FtpWriter getWriter() {
    return new DefaultFtpWriter();
}
```

But here I'm bound to a specific implementation. *How can I implement the part above to take properties into account and choose the correct implementation?*

A solution I come up with:

```
@Bean("writer1")
public FtpWriter oneWriter( 
        @Value("${writer1.ftp.username}") String username, 
        ...) {
    return this.getWriter(username, password, protocol, url, port, path);
}

private FtpWriter getWriter(String username, String password, String protocol, String URL, int port, String path) {
    FtpWriter writer;
    if ("sftp".equals(protocol)) {
        writer = new SftpWriter(username, password, protocol, url, port, path);
    } else {
        writer = new DefaultFtpWriter(username, password, protocol, url, port, path);
    }

    return writer;
}
```

To me, it seems a bit ugly to load the properties via @Value as method parameter directly.

Comment: Have you tried to user spring profiles functionality for that purpose?

Comment: @Leffchik, yes I tried spring profiles. But since I don't know which kind of servers were used in the different stages, I don't want to preconfigure the different combinations as property-files. Even "worse" the properties were not maintained by me.

Answer (score 0):

as @Leffchik already suggested, I'd also recommend using Spring profiles in this case. It sounds, as they perfectly suit your needs, even if I don't know your exact context and your restrictions to influence the runtime environment. But here is the relevant part in the reference documentation which might help you finding a better way to face your issues: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles

I agree with you, that your solution might work, but Spring profiles will lead to a cleaner code, as you would configure your beans like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class FtpConfiguration() {

    @Value("${writer1.ftp.username}")
    private String username;

    // more properties needed for creating writer instances
    // ...

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public FtpWriter defaultFtpWriter() {
        return new DefaultFtpWriter(username, ...);
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!dev")
    public FtpWriter sftpFtpWriter() {
        return new SftpWriter(username, ...);
    }

}
```

As I assume you'll probably use DefaultFtpWriter in local development environment and maybe in the first test stage. Beginning with stages above them, you'll probable use SftpWriter. Configure the writes this way addresses what you said about the properties, which will not be maintained by yourself (Anyway I think you will be able to control the properties when you are in local development and hopefully when you're in an environment for early (automated) tests). The only thing you have to do is, to activate the appropriate profile when you need DefaultFtpWriter. In this case you would provide a system environment variable `spring.profiles.active="dev"`.

Even if you have no control about your properties, you should be able to set this system variable (for example as JVM parameter on server startup: `-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"`) in certain stages. In stages nearer to production you probably even don't need to configure anything, as SftpWriter will be configured, as profile "dev" is no longer activated.